# Is there a way for saving changelogs in different languages in Debian

Tags: debian, i18n

Most of the changelogs, specifically upstream changelogs I have seen in Debian for e.g. `$ zcat /usr/share/doc/<$packaagename>/changelog.gz | less` shows the changelog only in English. If upstream wants to keep a changelog in different languages, in English as well as a different language, is there a way in Debian to know/tell/see if the changelog.gz is in different languages.  If there is a precedent, please share more.